# Moving the player freely all over the screen

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm making a game where the ball(the player) is suppose to avoid other balls passing by the screen. Basically I want the ball always to follow the location of the touch. So wherever I'm moving my finger on the screen, the ball follows.

This is the player Class:

```
import SpriteKit

struct ColliderType {

static let Player: UInt32 = 1
static let Blue: UInt32 = 2
static let Green: UInt32 = 3
static let Yellow: UInt32 = 4
static let Red: UInt32 = 5

}

class Player: SKSpriteNode {

func initialize() {
    self.name = "Player"
    self.zPosition = 1
    self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: self.size.height / 
 2)
    self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Player
    self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Blue | 
 ColliderType.Green | ColliderType.Red | ColliderType.Yellow
    self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Blue | 
 ColliderType.Green | ColliderType.Red | ColliderType.Yellow
 }

 }
```

This is the GameplayScene:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameplayScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

var player = Player()

var ball = SKSpriteNode()

var scoreLabel = SKLabelNode()
var score = 0

var counter = Timer()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    initialize()
}

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: 
UIEvent?) {


    for touch in touches {

        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        if atPoint(location).name == "Retry" {
            self.removeAllActions()
            self.removeAllChildren()
            initialize()
        }

        if atPoint(location).name == "Quit" {
            let mainmenu = MainMenuScene(fileNamed: "MainMenuScene")
            mainmenu!.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            self.view?.presentScene(mainmenu!, transition: 
 SKTransition.fade(withDuration: TimeInterval(1)))
        }

    }

}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: 
UIEvent?) {

}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: 
UIEvent?) {

}

func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    var firstBody = SKPhysicsBody()
    var secondBody = SKPhysicsBody()

    if contact.bodyA.node?.name == "Player" {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    if firstBody.node?.name == "Player" && secondBody.node?.name == 
"Red" {
        playerDied()
        firstBody.node?.removeFromParent()
    }

    if firstBody.node?.name == "Player" && secondBody.node?.name == 
"Blue" {
        playerDied()
        firstBody.node?.removeFromParent()
    }

    if firstBody.node?.name == "Player" && secondBody.node?.name == 
"Green" {
        playerDied()
        firstBody.node?.removeFromParent()
    }

    if firstBody.node?.name == "Player" && secondBody.node?.name == 
"Yellow" {
        playerDied()
        firstBody.node?.removeFromParent()
    }

}

func initialize() {

    score = 0

    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    createPlayer()
    createBackground()
    spawnRedBall()
    spawnBlueBall()
    spawnGreenBall()
    spawnYellowBall()
    createLabel()

    counter = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(0.7), 
target: self, selector: "incrementScore", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func createPlayer() {
    player = Player(imageNamed: "Player")
    player.initialize()
    player.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    self.addChild(player)
}

func createBackground() {
    let bg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "BG")
    bg.name = "BG"
    bg.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    bg.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    self.addChild(bg)
}

func createRedBall() {
    let ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Red")
    ball.name = "Red"
    ball.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    ball.zPosition = 1
    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.size.height / 
2)
    ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Red
    ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    ball.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

    ball.position.y = self.size.height + 100
    ball.position.x = CGFloat.randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: -345, 
secondNum: 345)

    self.addChild(ball)

    let destination = self.frame.height * 2
    let move = SKAction.moveTo(y: -destination, duration: 
TimeInterval(10))
    let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    ball.run(SKAction.sequence([move, remove]), withKey: "MoveRed")
}

func spawnRedBall() {

    let spawn = SKAction.run({ () -> Void in
        self.createRedBall()
    })

    let delay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: TimeInterval(0.5))
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([spawn, delay])

    self.run(SKAction.repeatForever(sequence), withKey: "SpawnRed")
}

func createBlueBall() {
    let ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Blue")
    ball.name = "Blue"
    ball.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    ball.zPosition = 1
    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.size.height / 
2)
    ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Blue
    ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    ball.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

    ball.position.y = -self.size.height + 100
    ball.position.x = CGFloat.randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: -345, 
secondNum: 345)

    self.addChild(ball)

    let destination = self.frame.height * 2
    let move = SKAction.moveTo(y: destination, duration: 
TimeInterval(10))
    let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    ball.run(SKAction.sequence([move, remove]), withKey: "MoveBlue")
}

func spawnBlueBall() {

    let spawn = SKAction.run({ () -> Void in
        self.createBlueBall()
    })

    let delay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: TimeInterval(0.5))
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([spawn, delay])

    self.run(SKAction.repeatForever(sequence), withKey: "SpawnBlue")
}

func createGreenBall() {
    let ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Green")
    ball.name = "Green"
    ball.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    ball.zPosition = 1
    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.size.height / 
2)
    ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Green
    ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    ball.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

    ball.position.x = -self.size.width + 200
    ball.position.y = CGFloat.randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: -637, 
secondNum: 637)

    self.addChild(ball)

    let destination = self.frame.height * 2
    let move = SKAction.moveTo(x: destination, duration: 
TimeInterval(10))
    let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    ball.run(SKAction.sequence([move, remove]), withKey: "MoveGreen")
}

func spawnGreenBall() {

    let spawn = SKAction.run({ () -> Void in
        self.createGreenBall()
    })

    let delay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: TimeInterval(0.5))
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([spawn, delay])

    self.run(SKAction.repeatForever(sequence), withKey: "SpawnGreen")
}

func createYellowBall() {
    let ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Yellow")
    ball.name = "Yellow"
    ball.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    ball.zPosition = 1
    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.size.height / 
2)
    ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Green
    ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    ball.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

    ball.position.x = self.size.width + 200
    ball.position.y = CGFloat.randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: -637, 
secondNum: 637)

    self.addChild(ball)

    let destination = self.frame.height * 2
    let move = SKAction.moveTo(x: -destination, duration: 
TimeInterval(10))
    let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    ball.run(SKAction.sequence([move, remove]), withKey: "MoveYellow")
}

func spawnYellowBall() {

    let spawn = SKAction.run({ () -> Void in
        self.createYellowBall()
    })

    let delay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: TimeInterval(0.5))
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([spawn, delay])

    self.run(SKAction.repeatForever(sequence), withKey: "SpawnYellow")
}

func createLabel() {
    scoreLabel.zPosition = 3
    scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: -320, y: 600)
    scoreLabel.fontName = "Verdana"
    scoreLabel.fontSize = 70
    scoreLabel.text = "0"
    self.addChild(scoreLabel)
}

func incrementScore() {
    score += 1
    scoreLabel.text = String(score)
}

func playerDied() {

    counter.invalidate()

    let highscore = GameManager.instance.getHighscore()

    if highscore < score {
        GameManager.instance.setHighscore(highscore: score)
    }

    let retry = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Retry")
    let quit = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Quit")

    retry.name = "Retry"
    retry.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    retry.position = CGPoint(x: -150, y: -50)
    retry.zPosition = 2
    retry.setScale(0)

    quit.name = "Quit"
    quit.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    quit.position = CGPoint(x: 150, y: -50)
    quit.zPosition = 2
    quit.setScale(0)

    let scaleUp = SKAction.scale(to: 1, duration: TimeInterval(0.5))

    retry.run(scaleUp)
    quit.run(scaleUp)

    self.addChild(retry)
    self.addChild(quit)

}

}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Do you want the ball to move to wherever you touch the screen, or do you want to implement 'drag-and-drop', whereby you have to touch the ball first before dragging it around?

Comment: When the game starts, the ball is in the center. Then the player puts his finger on the ball, and drags it around. So he cant just click on a location on the screen and the ball will get there. No, the ball follows the finger around on the screen. So for example when he lets go of the touch, the ball will stay put.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample project to show how to implement a draggable sprite.:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

var ballIsTouched = false
var ball = SKSpriteNode()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    ball = SKSpriteNode(color: .blue, size: CGSize(width:100, height:100))
    ball.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    addChild(ball)
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        if ball.contains(touch.location(in: self)) {
            ballIsTouched = true
        }
   }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if (ballIsTouched == true) {
        ball.position = (touches.first?.location(in: self))!
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    ballIsTouched = false
}


override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered
}
}
```

This only allows for the single specified sprite to be dragged. Here is an example with multiple sprites that can be dragged:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

extension SKColor {

static func random() -> SKColor {
    let colours = [SKColor.lightGray, SKColor.white, SKColor.gray, SKColor.red, SKColor.green, SKColor.blue, SKColor.cyan, SKColor.yellow, SKColor.magenta, SKColor.orange, SKColor.purple, SKColor.brown]
    return colours[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(colours.count)))]
}

}

class GameScene: SKScene {

var touchedSprite : SKSpriteNode?

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    for i in -1...1 {
    let ball = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.random(), size: CGSize(width:100, height:100))
    ball.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: i * 200)
    addChild(ball)
    }
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        touchedSprite = self.atPoint(touch.location(in: self)) as? SKSpriteNode
        touchedSprite?.setScale(1.25)
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if (touchedSprite != nil) {
        touchedSprite?.position = (touches.first?.location(in: self))!
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
                touchedSprite?.setScale(1)
    touchedSprite = nil
}


override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered
}
}
```

You could also implement a `draggable` protocol or something to limit which sprites can be dragged.

Comment: This won't work - you test if the touch is within the ball and only then move the ball, but the ball won't move very far. If the touch is on the other side of the screen, nothing will happen.

Comment: That's what the OP wanted

Comment: this only lets you move the ball if you're touching it

Comment: @JamalH Ok - I see what you're doing. Have you tested this method? I would imagine that it could work but only if you move your finger slowly - should your finger move outside of the node in between calls to `touchesMoved` then you'd 'drop' the ball.

Comment: @SteveIves, I now have implemented the code that Jamal wrote and you're right. As soon as the finger "leaves" the ball, the ball stops. How would you make so that the player can be allowed to "leave" the ball and the ball moves in the direction of the touch?

Comment: @Flinigan I'll try to write an example and post it.

Comment: Thank you, that would be so great!! :)

Comment: @SteveIves, How is it going? =)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following property:

```
   var ballIsTouched = false
```

and then implement the `touch` methods:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let location = touches.first.location(in: self) {
        if ball.containsPoint(location) {
            ballIsTouched = true 
        }
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if (ballIsTouched == true) {
        ball.position = (touches.first?.location(in: self))!
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    ballIsTouched = false
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but the ball is static. It isn't moving at all. :(

Comment: @Flinigan. sorry for not getting back to you. Can you post the code you are using at them moment to move the ball?

Comment: for touch in (touches ) {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            if player.contains(location) {
                player.position = location
            }
        }

Comment: This works okay, but when the touch is not on the ball, it stops. And since it's a game where the player has to be quick in movement, the current code is not exactly ideal.

Comment: Is this in `touchesMoved` or `touchesBegan`?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is more natural when implementing a dragging, to drag a sprite from the touch location rather than from the center of the sprite. To do this, you should calculate the offset and add it the new sprite's position, like this:

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch in touches {

            let current =  touch.location(in: self)
            let previous = touch.previousLocation(in: self)

            if ball.contains(current) {

                let offset = CGPoint(x: current.x - previous.x , y: current.y - previous.y)
                ball.position = CGPoint(x: ball.position.x + offset.x , y: ball.position.y + offset.y)
            }
        }
    }
```